# Express.js basic routing from index.js file

Tags: routes, express

I want to create 2 pages, using 2 jade files. What is wrong in the following way:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
    res.render('index', { title: 'Welcome' });
};

exports.room = function(req, res){
    res.render('room', { title: 'Game' });
};
```

The index `localhost:3000` works. but `localhost:3000/room` gives me

```
Cannot GET /room
```

Comment: how does your main `app.js` file look like? do you have a `app.get('/room', routes.room)` route or something like this?

Comment: @zeMirco yes, I did it now and it solved the problem. you can write as an answer. Do I have to do it for each page? what if I have lots of pages, is there a way to get all the pages in `index.js` routes file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the route to your main `app.js` file

```
app.get('/room', routes.room);
```

For lots of page you could do something like

```
var routes = ['blog', 'about', 'home', 'team', 'room', ...];

routes.forEach(function(item) {
  exports[item] = function(req, res) {
    res.render(item);
  }
});
```

However if you've got lots of individual local variables this might get messy too (you could use Objects inside the Array instead of Strings).

So the best thing would be to put your `POST` and `GET` requests concerning `/room` into a `room.js` and require it inside your main `app.js`. Then you can use it like this

```
var room = require('./routes/room');

app.get('/room', room.read);
app.post('/room', room.create);
app.get('/room/:id', room.getID);
app.get('/room/anything', room.anything);

// then continue with app.get('/team') for example
```

Also take a look at the [route-separation](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/route-separation/user.js) example at the express github repo.